# C struct and use C dll in C#

Tags: c#, c

everyone, I'm newbie in C#, and I have a problem with using "C" dll in C#, below is the C side code which work fine.

```
// myCode.h
typedef struct _SubABC
{
    unsigned short  WordCount;                                     
    unsigned char  *WordData;
    unsigned char   SpeedUp;
} SubABC;

typedef struct _ABC
{
    unsigned char   SubFontNum;
    SubABC subABC[5]; 
} ABC

extern __declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall MY_SetSth(unsigned char SerialNum, ABC *pABC);


//myCode.c
ABC myFun = { '\0' };
unsigned char text_c[] =
{
    0x00,0x27,0xff,0xA5,0xC3, 0x00,0x27,0xff,0xA6,0x26, 0x00,0x23,0xff,0xA7,0xAE, 0x00,0x27,0xff,0xBA,0x7E,
    0x00,0x27,0xff,0xC1,0x52, 0x00,0x27,0xff,0xAC,0xF9, 0x00,0x27,0xff,0x20,0x00,0x27,0xff,0x31, 0x00,0x27,0xff,0x20, 0x00,0x27,0xff,0xA4,0xC0, 0x00,0x27,0xff,0xC4,0xC1,

};
myFun.SubFontNum = 1;
myFun.subMABC[0].WordCount = sizeof(text_c);
myFun.subMABC[0].WordData = text_c;
myFun.subMABC[0].SpeedUp = 0;
int retvalue = MY_SetSth(1, &myFun);
```

and my C# code is below

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct SubABC
{
    public ushort WordCount;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
    public byte[] WordData;
    public byte SpeedUp;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct ABC
{
    public byte   SubFontNum;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)]
    public SubABC[] subABC;
}

[DllImport("myDLL.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public extern static int MY_SetSth(byte SerialNum, ref ABC pABC);


ABC myFun = new ABC();
ABC.subABC = new SubABC[5];
unsigned char text_c[] =
{
    0x00,0x27,0xff,0xA5,0xC3, 0x00,0x27,0xff,0xA6,0x26, 0x00,0x23,0xff,0xA7,0xAE, 0x00,0x27,0xff,0xBA,0x7E,
    0x00,0x27,0xff,0xC1,0x52, 0x00,0x27,0xff,0xAC,0xF9, 0x00,0x27,0xff,0x20,0x00,0x27,0xff,0x31, 0x00,0x27,0xff,0x20, 0x00,0x27,0xff,0xA4,0xC0, 0x00,0x27,0xff,0xC4,0xC1,

};
myFun.SubFontNum = 1;
myFun.subMABC[0].WordCount = (ushort)text_c.Length;
myFun.subMABC[0].WordData = text_c;
myFun.subMABC[0].SpeedUp = 0;
int retvalue = MY_SetSth(1, ref myFun);
```

I always get `TypeLoadException: Cannot marshal field 'WordData' of type 'subABC': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Array fields must be paired with ByValArray or SafeArray)`, because WordData is unknown size, I can't use ByValArray, and SafeArray get `AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory`

I try to use IntPtr like below

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct SubABC
{
    public ushort WordCount;
    public IntPtr WordData;
    public byte SpeedUp;
}
ABC.subABC[0].WordData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(text_c.Length); ;
Marshal.Copy(text_c, 0, ABC.subABC[0].WordData, text_c.Length);
int retvalue = MY_SetSth(1, ref myFun);
```

I get error message `AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory`
Can anyone help me? thank a lot.

Comment: Can you share the error details? You can define `WordData` as `IntPtr` and then marshal it to required type

Comment: Please, have a look at this MSDN [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-different-types-of-arrays) I guess, that you should use `Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem` method instead of `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`

Comment: Looks okay.  How "MY_SetSth" transmogrified into "LEDEth_MY_SetSth" is hard to guess.  You'll have to debug this on the C side.

Comment: Hi, Pavel, I try to use  ```Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem ```, but still get ```AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory```. Hi, Hans, sorry it's a typo, it should be MY_SetSth.